# Write lowercase in Section (IEEEtran class)

Tags: sectioning, formatting, ieeetran

I want to write lower case in a section, I've tried using `\MakeLowercase` but its not working. Here is what I tried:

```
\section{Experiment I: T\MakeLowercase{he effect of changing the distance}}
```

I'm using the [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) document class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) sets up the `\section` titles in the normal (or standard LaTeX2e) way using `\@startsection`. The font choice for sections are `\normalfont\normalsize\centering\scshape`:

```
\def\section{%
  \@startsection{section}% type
    {1}% level
    {\z@}% indent
    {1.5ex plus 1.5ex minus 0.5ex}% top separation before heading
    {1sp}% bottom separation after heading
    {\normalfont\normalsize\centering\scshape}}% font
```

`\scshape` here is the problem for you. So all you need to do is insert `\normalfont` at the appropriate place:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://ctan.org/pkg/IEEEtran
\begin{document}
\section{Experiment I: \normalfont The effect of changing the distance}
\end{document}
```

Note that they choose their definitions for a purpose. So, changing it might not be a good idea.

Comment: This did not work for me; however, `\lowercase{The effect of changing the distance}` did the job.

Comment: @Isi: Can you provide a minimal example showing where it did/does not work? Definitions within the [`IEEEtran`](//ctan.org/pkg/IEEEtran) document class still remain very similar (last updated 2015, 2 years after this answer).

Comment: Sure! This did not have an effect: `\section{Experiment I: \normalfont The effect of changing the distance}`, but this worked: `\section{Experiment I: \lowercase{The effect of changing the distance}}`

Comment: @Isi: My minimal example still compiles to show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ9Sp.png), which means I can't replicate your issue.

Comment: I'm so sorry, my bad! I was not using IEEEtran but IEEEaccess (https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/guide-for-authors/submission-guidelines/).